# python-click: using custom helpformatter to overwrite prefix for multiline-prefix

Tags: python-3.x, python-click

I would like to add a multi-line `prefix` to the help output when calling may cli tool, e.g. `mytool --help` to look like:

```
This is mytool cli tool  
as part of tool-suite abc.


Usage: mytool [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

  

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  version  Display package version.
  ...
```

so the text

```
This is my cli tool xyz 
as part of tool-suite abc.
```

should appear before the usual

`Usage: ...`-text

Just can't figure out to pass my custom HelpFormatter to the group.

Does someone have an example on how to define the custom HelpFormatter and then override the write_usage or format_usage method accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

Below you can find one of the basic click examples from the documentation with added code overriding the `HelpFormatter`.

The essence is, that you need to override the `Context.formatter_class` class variable. Keep in mind, that this was added in Click 8.0. If you are using Click prior to that version, you probably need to override the`Context.make_formatter()` method.

```py
import click


class MyHelpFormatter(click.HelpFormatter):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(self, **kwargs)
        self.indent_increment = 6


click.Context.formatter_class = MyHelpFormatter

@click.command()
@click.option('--count', default=1, help='Number of greetings.')
@click.option('--name', prompt='Your name',
              help='The person to greet.')
def hello(count, name):
    """Simple program that greets NAME for a total of COUNT times."""
    for x in range(count):
        click.echo(f'Hello {name}!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello()
```

For more information, you can read the [documentaion here](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/api/?highlight=helpformatter#click.Context.make_formatter).

If you need more fine grained control over the formatting, you could create custom Command classes and override the [format_help() method](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/api/?highlight=helpformatter#click.Context.make_formatter). This way, you could have different formatter for each command, or group of commands (which is generally a bad idea, but still possible)