# Is there way to customize col_max value without change python-click source code?

Tags: python-click

I'm facing a very concrete problem with python-click 8.1.3. The helptext created by Click wastes too much column space when an option name is a tad long. Depicted in picture below:

[image: Helptext space waste]

I trace into Click's source code, and pinpoint a hardcoded value in `HelpFormatter.write_dl()`, the `col_max` parameter determines first-column max-width, which is 30, and I hope to reduce it to 16.

[image: PyCharm debugging HelpFormatter.write_dl()]

As a Click-library user, how can I achieve this without modifying Click's source code? Maybe some class inheritance or patching trick?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```py
class MyHelpFormatter(click.HelpFormatter):
    def write_dl(self, rows, col_max=5, col_spacing=2):
        super().write_dl(rows, col_max, col_spacing)


click.Context.formatter_class = MyHelpFormatter
```

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73098270/python-click-using-custom-helpformatter-to-overwrite-prefix-for-multiline-prefi/73188760#73188760) for a similar example